# Anyone know what this ground cover is

Tags: identification

Anyone know what this is. It looks like a ground cover, it came up after buying a store-bought mulch. In one year it has taken over my garden, the roots are close to the surface. No flowers appear. I live in Ontario canada[image]

Comment: Ground elder (Aegopodium podagraria) , although I'm not 100%

Comment: @Nic you really should make this an answer.

Comment: Good luck. The stuff is extremely aggressive.

Answer (score 1):

As @Nic mentioned in his comment this should be ground elder. One of its dominant optical features is that the number three is the dominant number of leafs and forks it has.
For some more information about the plant click  [here](http://healingweeds.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/ground-elder.html).